# How to get initial GeoFire values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geocoding, geofire

I am having a bit of a problem with [geofire-js](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md).

I have two different kind of users in my app. Users and Workers.
Basically users post Jobs and workers are able to see those jobs. But I only wanna show jobs to workers that are close to the current user.

So after creating a job and submitting it to firebase I am querying from the user client to geofire to fetch me all the users around him:

```
function getNearbyUsers(job) {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('/geofire/workerUsers');

  let geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);

  let geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [job.lat, job.lng],
    radius: 4
  });

  // How do I get initial data from here?

  geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
    console.log("GeoQuery has loaded and fired all other events for initial data");
  });

  geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
    console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
  });

  geoQuery.on("key_exited", function(key, location, distance) {
    console.log(key + " exited query to " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
  });

  geoQuery.on("key_moved", function(key, location, distance) {
    console.log(key + " moved within query to " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
  });
}
```

Now it appears to me that I can only listen to keys that moved into te query area and to those who leave it. That is great.

But how do I get the INITIAL DATA? (from the users already within the query area)

This is a picture of some dummy WORKER user I have in the db, that is clearly withing the query area.

[image]

I am sorry if its evident and I am missing something out.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your geoquery, the `key_entered` event immediate fires for each key already in the range.

The [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback) indeed doesn't mention this explicitly. But when you run the code, you'll see that it gives you the relevant keys straight away.

Comment: This is the assumption that I made, but I see that the getNearbyUsers function is being called but none of the callbacks are getting triggered :/

Comment: Is `ready` not getting triggered either? If so, check the dev console of your browser for errors.

Comment: No, the ready is not getting triggerd. I checked the console. I am using geofire in my react-native app. But I have seen examples of react-native apps using it, so I do not think that it is the issue here.

Comment: The issue was my db rules. Since the doc functions dont catch errors I did not see anything in my console. Thank you for your help Frank! :)

Comment: The functions provided in the API documentation do not console log errors apparently, because I did not get a warning like I usually do when I am trying to read from a location I am not authorized to.